# Laravel wherebetween datetime

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, query-builder

I have a problem using wherebetween to filter data by timestamp (datetime)

To test query, this is my route

```
Route::get('/test3/{iduser}/{waktu}', 'SharedController@fgetxy_person');
```

and this is URL test

```
http://localhost:8000/test3/32/2020-12-08 2010:15:00
```

this is my controller

```
public function fgetxy_person($iduser, $waktu){
        $time = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $waktu, 'Asia/Jakarta');
        // dd($time->addMinutes(-5)); //output: 10:10:00
        // dd($time->addMinutes(30)); //output: 10:45:00
        $xybeacon = DB::table('transaksi as tb')
        ->select('tb.id_ble', 'tb.rssi', 'tb.id_ble2', 'tb.rssi2', 'tb.id_ble3', 'tb.rssi3','tb.updated_at')
        ->where('id_user', $iduser)
        ->whereBetween('updated_at', [$time->addMinutes(-5), $time->addMinutes(30)])    //output: []
        // ->whereBetween('updated_at', array($time->addMinutes(-5), $time->addMinutes(30)))    // output: []
        // ->where('updated_at','>=',$time->addMinutes(-5))    //output: 94 array
        // ->where('updated_at','<=',$time->addMinutes(30)) //output: 35 array
        
        // ->whereRaw(
        //     "(updated_at >= ? AND updated_at <= ?)", 
        //     [$time, $time->addMinutes(30)]
        //   )  //output: []
        
        ->get();
```

The problem is, I cannot get data using wherebetween.

If I try used 1 where, for example addMinutes(-5), I can get the data.

but when used 2 where addMinutes(-5) and addMinutes(30), I get empty array []

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: `2020-12-08 2010:15:00` doesn't look like a correct datetime

Comment: im sure it is correct because i can addMinutes and tested (dd($time->addMinutes(-5)); //output: 10:10:00)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default carbon instances are mutable, meaning if you are using the same instance you will always be using the same time. You should switch to immutable Carbon instances.

```
public function fgetxy_person($iduser, $waktu){
        $time = CarbonImmutable::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $waktu, 'Asia/Jakarta');
        $xybeacon = DB::table('transaksi as tb')
        ->select('tb.id_ble', 'tb.rssi', 'tb.id_ble2', 'tb.rssi2', 'tb.id_ble3', 'tb.rssi3','tb.updated_at')
        ->where('id_user', $iduser)
        ->whereBetween('updated_at', [$time->addMinutes(-5), $time->addMinutes(30)])        
        ->get();
```

This will ensure that the two parameters in `whereBetween` refer to a different time.

The difference is that all functions that change the time on the instance will return a new instance with that time instead of returning the same instance with the time changed.